# Using WP_Query() to query newer posts, using post ID in the WHERE filter?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was wondering if there is a way using WP_Query (get_posts, etc) to return posts with an ID greater than one that is provided..

I've been through the WordPress codex and missed any reference to querying posts related to a post ID, if it's even possible without a custom query.

Since it doesn't seep possible to pass it through with the arguments, I've tried writing a method that modifies the [posts_where](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter but that doesn't seem to work either..

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_since_id');
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    // Do Stuff
endwhile;
remove_filter('posts_where' , 'filter_since_id');
```

...

```
function filter_since_id($where = ''){
    $where .= " AND ID > 3'";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: The posts_where filter should be working for you here, but why have you got a trailing single quote?  $where .= " AND ID > 3'";
 SHOULD BE  $where .= " AND ID > 3";

Comment: Oops. The single quote, was present because I replaced a variable with 3.. But that pointed me to another typo, thanks for the quick answer/help.

Answer (score 0):

Clarified so that someone passing through can grab and go:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'filter_since_id');

function filter_since_id($where = ''){
    $where .= " AND ID > 3";
    return $where;
}
```